# Getting Python's nosetests results in a tearDown() method

Tags: python, nose

I want to be able to get the result of a particular test method and output it inside the teardown method, while using the nose test runner.
There is a very good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415062/1566170).

But unfortunately, running `nosetests example.py` does not work, since nose doesn't seem to like the fact that the run method in the superclass is being overridden:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'wasSuccessful'
```

Answer (score 5):

Caveat: the following doesn't actually access the test during the tearDown, but it does access each result.

You might want to write a nose plugin ([see the API documentation here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html)).  The method that you are probably interested in is `afterTest()`, which is run... after the test. :)  Though, depending on your exact application, `handleError()`/`handleFailure()` or `finalize()` might actually be more useful.

Here is an example plugin that accesses the result of a test immediately after it is executed.

```
from nose.plugins import Plugin
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('nose.plugins.testnamer')

class ReportResults(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReportResults, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.passes = 0
        self.failures = 0
    def afterTest(self, test):
        if test.passed:
            self.passes += 1
        else:
            self.failures += 1
    def finalize(self, result):
        print "%d successes, %d failures" % (self.passes, self.failures)
```

This trivial example merely reports the number of passes and failures (like the link you included, but I'm sure you can extend it to do something more interesting ([here's another fun idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14077299/1309332)).  To use this, make sure that it is installed in Nose (or load it into a custom runner), and then activate it with --with-reportresults.

Comment: Your code shows errors in these lines:
passes += 1 and failures += 1 (Undefined variable error)

Comment: Thanks. I'll add initialization.

Answer (score -1):

If you are OK with adding some boilerplate code to the tests, something like the following might work.

In MyTest1, `tearDown` is called at the end of each test, and the value of self.result has been set to a tuple containing the method name and a dictionary (but you could set that to whatever you like).  The inspect module is used to get the method name, so `tearDown` knows which test just ran.

In MyTest2, *all* the results are saved in a dictionary (`results`), which you can do with what you like in the `tearDownClass` method.

```
import inspect
import unittest


class MyTest1(unittest.TestCase):

    result = None

    def tearDown(self):
        print "tearDown:", self.result

    def test_aaa(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
        del frame
        self.result = (name, None)

        x = 1 + 1
        self.assertEqual(x, 2)

        self.result = (name, dict(x=x))

    def test_bbb(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
        del frame
        self.result = (name, None)

        # Intentional fail.
        x = -1
        self.assertEqual(x, 0)

        self.result = (name, dict(x=x))


class MyTest2(unittest.TestCase):

    results = {}

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print "tearDownClass:", cls.results

    def test_aaa(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
        del frame
        self.results[name] = None

        x = 1 + 1
        self.assertEqual(x, 2)

        self.results[name] = dict(x=x)

    def test_bbb(self):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        name = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function
        del frame
        self.results[name] = None

        x = -1
        self.assertEqual(x, 0)

        self.results[name] = dict(x=x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: As this is a bit hackish and possibly brittle (e.g. not tested in python 3), the downvote is probably deserved.  I wouldn't use it in my own production code.  On the other hand, it seems to work; practicality beats purity and all that.