# Automatic screenshots when test fail by Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I want to automatic capturing screenshots if my webdriver tests failed (any exception or assertion error). I am using Python unittest and Selenium Webdriver. Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 28):

do some webdriver stuff in Firefox... save screenshot on any exception to a dated image file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    # do some webdriver stuff here
except Exception as e:
    print e
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    browser.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot-%s.png' % now)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that it was a right way using try:except and now I saw this

Comment: This works well, but swallowing the exception this way stops the unit test harness from reporting an error. 

If using this code in a unittest class containing multiple tests, it's worth adding 'raise e' to the  end of the except block.

Answer (score 11):

Another method would be to add the following to your `tearDown` method:

```
if sys.exc_info()[0]:
    test_method_name = self._testMethodName
    self.driver.save_screenshot("Screenshots/%s.png" % test_method_name)
```

This would be assuming a test class like this:

```
class SeleniumTest(unittest2.TestCase):
    ...

    def tearDown(self):
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            test_method_name = self._testMethodName
            self.driver.save_screenshot("Screenshots/%s.png" % test_method_name)
        super(SeleniumTest, self).tearDown()

    def test_1(self):
        ...

    def test_2(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 10):

For Future reference/People here is a solution that works in Python3, that works both for an Exception and on a failed Assert.

(Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176373/9427691)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
An Example code to show the set-up with screen-shot on exception.
"""

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class TestDemo(unittest.TestCase):
    """An Example test Case, to show off the set-up of a screen-shot on exception."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Set up the Firefox Browser and the Tear Down."""
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
        # NOTE: In addCleanup, the first in, is executed last.
        self.addCleanup(self.driver.quit)
        self.addCleanup(self.screen_shot)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    def screen_shot(self):
        """Take a Screen-shot of the drive homepage, when it Failed."""
        for method, error in self._outcome.errors:
            if error:
                self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot" + self.id() + ".png")

    def test_demo(self):
        """A test case that fails because of missing element."""
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.that-does-not-exist")

    def test_demo2(self):
        """A test case that fails because assert."""
        self.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
        self.assertEqual(True, False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

The

> self._outcome.errors

are Python3 only, so for Python2 use

> self._outcomeForDoCleanups.errors

instead.

For the ones that only want a Screen-shot on exceptions. You should take a look at this link: http://blog.likewise.org/2015/01/automatically-capture-browser-screenshots-after-failed-python-ghostdriver-tests/

Comment: Instead of adding the screen_shot method through addCleanup(), it is also possible to place the logic in tearDown()

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using a decorator that wrapps every method on a class that starts `test_` with a wrapper that takes a screenshot if the method raises and Exception. The `browser_attr` is used to tell the decorator how to obtain the web browser (driver).

```
from functools import partialmethod


def sreenshotOnFail(browser_attr='browser'):
    def decorator(cls):
        def with_screen_shot(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
            """Take a Screen-shot of the drive page, when a function fails."""
            try:
                return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception:
                # This will only be reached if the test fails
                browser = getattr(self, browser_attr)
                filename = 'screenshot-%s.png' % fn.__name__
                browser.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
                print('Screenshot saved as %s' % filename)
                raise

        for attr, fn in cls.__dict__.items():
            if attr[:5] == 'test_' and callable(fn):
                setattr(cls, attr, partialmethod(with_screen_shot, fn))

        return cls
    return decorator


@sreenshotOnFail()
class TestDemo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Set up the Firefox Browser and the Tear Down."""
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_demo2(self):
        """A test case that fails because assert."""
        self.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
        self.assertEqual(True, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start form exploring `self._outcome.errors[1]` where it is possible to find information about the errors.
i.e. below code will work only for assertion errors

```
 def tearDown(self):
        if self._outcome.errors[1][1] and hasattr(self._outcome.errors[1][1][1], 'actual'):
            self.driver.save_screenshot(self._testMethodName + '.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
   page2.fill_up_company_info()
except Exception as e:
   with pytest.raises(WebDriverException):
            pytest.fail( f"{e} for error message",       
allure.attach(self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(),name="screenshot",attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG))
```

Comment: can you give an explanation as to why the above code works?

Answer (score 0):

For Django 2.2.2 (which uses unittest) in my class for selenium tests, which inherited from StaticLiveServerTestCase I've overrided _feedErrorsToResult method. Also this approach provides tricky way to know name of called method for convinient screenshot investigation.

```py
@classmethod
def _feedErrorsToResult(cls, result, errors):
    """
    Overriding private method at %library root%/Lib/unittest/case.py
    so you can take screenshot with any failed test and find name of the method
    """
    if SELENIUM_TAKE_SCREENSHOTS:
        for test, exc_info in errors:
            if exc_info is not None:
                now = datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
                test_name = exc_info[2].tb_frame.f_locals["test_case"]._testMethodName
                # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
                cls.selenium.get_screenshot_as_file('%s/%s-%s-%s.png' % (SELENIUM_SCREENSHOTS_PATH, cls.__name__, test_name, now))
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    super()._feedErrorsToResult(cls, result, errors)
```

Answer (score -2):

For me help this solution:

```
def teardown_method(self, method):
    """Driver elimination"""
    if sys.exc_info():
        allure.attach('screenshot', self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), type=AttachmentType.PNG)
    self.driver.quit()
    pass
```