# Selenium python - take screenshot on failure and save it into a folder

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to take a screenshot with selenium python on failure. I have written 30 tests and I want to add something in my tear down method in my base class method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024848/automatic-screenshots-when-test-fail-by-selenium-webdriver-in-python.

Answer (score 0):

You could to a `try` block and call `browser.get_screenshot_as_file()` on failure.