# How do I view the "Screenshot: available via screen"?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs, screen, screenshot

I have started running Selenium tests via PhantomJS from Python. Whenever a test raises an exception I see a traceback followed by the enigmatic phrase

> Screenshot: available via screen

It would be nice to be able to view such screenshots, but I have no idea where they are being saved, nor what program (or other) is intended by `screen`.

(The only "screen" I am familiar with is [the terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), which will not show screenshots)

So - what "screen" are they talking about? How do I use it to view the screenshots?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic screenshots when test fail by Selenium Webdriver in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024848/automatic-screenshots-when-test-fail-by-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: The solution to that question is the same, but I think the question is significantly different in that this question is asking about the specific error message. One reason I asked this question was I found it impossible to find any explanation of the error message, all searching just found it as part of an error log. I think this question should be retained for anyone else who finds themselves asking, like I did, "what does that error even mean???"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Run the program in a try block 
and when the error occur take the screenshot using save_screenshot

Eg :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)
try:
    driver.get('http://whatsmyuseragent.com/')

except Exception,e:
    driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')

driver.close()
```

This will give you the screenshot during that moment
Image will be saved at the working of your script

Comment: Interesting approach with the exception handling. As a side note you can aslo take a screenshot with `driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')`

Answer (score 7):

> So - what "screen" are they talking about?

My exception looks like this:

```
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"script-src 'self' connect.facebook.net cdn.ravenjs.com www.google-analytics.com banhang.shopee.vn chat.shopee.vn cdn.shopee.vn\".\n","request":{"objectName":"","statusCode":200,"headers":{"Cache":"no-cache","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Take a look at the line: `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)`, so the `screen` here means the variable `screen`:

```
>>> screen
u'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAYAAADPPjzCAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAgAElE ...'
```

I don't know a quick way to show the screenshot, but `screen` looks like the image data that you can save to a file then view it.

Answer (score 5):

I found that I can get the actual screenshot returned by the exception using the following (python3).

```
try:
    ...
except ElementNotVisibleException as e:
    with open("imageToSave.png", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(base64.decodebytes(e.screen.encode()))
```

The driver.save_screenshot() function creates a new screenshot at a time later than when the exception occurred.