# How do I use unittest.TestResult?

Tags: python, unit-testing, jython

I've only been using unittest for a short time. I am using Jython 2.7.10 "final release"

In the Python 2.7 docs explaining TestResult it says:

> The following methods of the TestResult class are used to maintain the
>   internal data structures, and may be extended in subclasses to support
>   additional reporting requirements. This is particularly useful in
>   building tools which support interactive reporting while tests are
>   being run.
>
> startTest(test) ... stopTest(test) ... startTestRun() ... stopTestRun()¶

That's what I want to do... but I can't work out how you use TestResult.  Here's an SSCCE...

```
import unittest

class TestResultX( unittest.TestResult ):
    def startTest( self, test ):
        print( '# blip')
        unittest.TestResult.startTest( self, test )
    def stopTest( self, test ):
        print( '# blop')
        unittest.TestResult.stopTest( self, test )
    def startTestRun( self ):
        print( '# blep')
        unittest.TestResult.startTestRun( self )
    def stopTestRun( self ):
        print( '# blap')
        unittest.TestResult.stopTestRun( self )

class TestCaseX( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_nonsense(self):
        print( '# wotcha' )
        self.assertTrue( False )

    def run( self, test_result=None ):
        print( '# spoons starting...')

        test_result = TestResultX()
        unittest.TestCase.run( self, test_result )

        print( '# ...spoons ended, tr %s' % ( test_result,  ) )

unittest.main()
```

Results in:

```
# spoons starting...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.015s

OK
# blip
# wotcha
# blop
# ...spoons ended, tr <__main__.TestResultX run=1 errors=0 failures=1>
```

Questions:

- Why does it say `0 tests`?
- Why are `blep` and `blap` (start and end of run) not printed?

On a more general note:

1. Can someone possibly point to a good tutorial/book explaining "proper use"/"good practice" when it comes to TestResult, TestRunner, TestLoader, etc. I got "TDD with Python", but it doesn't seem to explain any of this.
2. Can someone possibly tell me why unittest2 often seems to be used instead of unittest?

***addendum***

Following Omar Diab's efforts at looking at the source code I tried this:

```
def run( self, *args, **kvargs ):
    result = self.defaultTestResult()
    startTestRun = getattr(result, 'startTestRun', None)
    logger.info( '# calling superclass run... startTestRun? %s' % ( startTestRun, ))
    unittest.TestCase.run( self, *args, **kvargs  )
    logger.info( '# ... superclass run ended')
```

Unfortunately each test_XXX method then gave:

```
# calling superclass run... startTestRun? <bound method TestResult.startTestRun of <unittest.result.TestResult run=0 errors=0 failures=0>>

setUp for test_that_stuff_happened (__main__.xx_FT)

tearDown for test_that_stuff_happened (__main__.xx_FT)
end tearDown...
. # ... superclass run ended
```

Comment: I'm running into this—gotta say, the documentation for all this is pretty awful...

Comment: Related: [Getting Python's unittest results in a tearDown() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414234/getting-pythons-unittest-results-in-a-teardown-method)

Answer (score 3):

Wow, no responses. I'm surprised.

This is a hack which most people could no doubt work out for themselves, if you want stuff to happen at the start of the run and end of the run:

Subclass TestCase, as per:

```
def setUp( self ):
    if not hasattr( unittest.TestCase, 'app' ):
        unittest.TestCase.app = MyApp()
        def shutdown_func():
            pass # do any end-of-run stuff here
        atexit.register( shutdown_func )
        pass # do any start-of-run stuff here
    self.app = unittest.TestCase.app
```

Then make all your `TestCases` subclass from this one...

The point being, if you want this to happen, that your app is only constructed once. Handling the responsibility of ensuring that it is "pristine" for each successive `setUp` is up to you of course.
Obviously you could use `setUpClass` instead but then you don't have access to the `TestCase` instance.

Comment: I could not understand how to use your example. Can you create a minimal working example?

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem, so I took a look at the source code.

Inspecting `unittest.TextTestRunner` and `unittest.TestCase`, it looks like `startTestRun()` and `stopTestRun()` get called manually. In `unittest.TextTestRunner`, it works like so:

```
def run(self, test):
    # ...
    startTestRun = getattr(result, 'startTestRun', None)
    if startTestRun is not None:
        startTestRun()
    # ...
```

and in your case, `unittest.TestCase`, it is like so:

```
def run(self, result=None):
    orig_result = result
    if result is None:
        result = self.defaultTestResult()
        startTestRun = getattr(result, 'startTestRun', None)
        if startTestRun is not None:
            startTestRun()
    # ...
```

So it looks like `startTestRun` only actually gets called by `TestCase.run()` if you don't pass in `result`. You're passing in `result`, so it's not happening.

This seems like a bug to me! But basically it means you can extend `TestCase` or `TestSuite`, reimplement the run method, and then call those methods by hand; or just call them outside of those respective `run` methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for looking at the source code.  Should've done so myself, of course!  Unfortunately your suggestion of re-engineering the run method didn't work for me.  See the addendum I'm making to the original post...

Answer (score -1):

Think the creation of the TestResult object in `TestCase.run()` is misunderstood as no access to stream, descriptions, verbosity.
provide as KWarg it works

```
def run( self, test_result=TestResultX ):
or create TestResult in Runner.run():
```